# Excluir de uma lista os elementos de uma outra lista

Tags: python

Eu queria saber como poderia excluir de uma  lista, os elementos de outra lista (que será usada #para treino) e ficar somente com os elementos para teste, contidos dentro da lista inicial.

Tentei deixar um executável:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Created on Fri Mar 27 15:13:49 2020

# import random  
import random 


lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
print("Lista:", lista)

# Fixar uma semente e dado uma lista escolher parte dela, exemplo, 7 ids aleatorios
random.seed(0.72)   # Setar uma semente
idtrain = list(set(random.sample(lista, 7)))
print("Train animals:", idtrain) 

# indexar
#index = list.index(idtrain)
#list(x.keys()).index(idtrain)
#print("The index of idtrain:", index)


# Excluir os ids que estao nos treinos para ficar somente os ids dos testes
#tentativa 1
idteste = lista.extend(idtrain)

#tentativa 2
idteste = lista.remove(idtrain)

#tentativa 3
if(idtrain in lista):
    idteste = lista.remove(idtrain)

#tentativa 4
idteste = list(filter(lambda a: a != idtrain, lista))

#tentativa 5
while idtrain in lista:
    lista.remove(idtrain)

# tentativa 6
for i in idtrain:
    print(i)
    idteste = lista.remove(i)

print(idteste)

print("Test animals:", idteste)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [compreensão de listas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista):

```
idteste = [item for item in lista if item not in idtrain]
```

Outro método possível é a utilização de [Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).
Sets podem ser subtraídos um dos outros para obtenção dos itens diferentes:

```
idteste = list( set(lista) - set(idtrain) )
```

Claro, como set's não possuem ordem, e não permitem repetição, deve-se atentar neste método que você irá perder elementos duplicados da lista original, e também perderá a ordem em que eles aparecem.

Pergunta relacionada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4211209/10746978) (em inglês)